# How to show the multivariable remainder goes to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to show that

$$\lim_{(s,t)\to (0,0)}\frac{|3s^2t+t^2s^2|}{\sqrt{s^2+t^2}}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{(s,t)\to (0,0)}\frac{|st|}{\sqrt{s^2+t^2}}=0$$

I'm having some trouble proving that both go to zero. I feel that the second one is pretty obvious as the denominator dominates. But proving them rigorously has failed me. Is there an easy trick to break up the square root or use a comparison?

Thanks

Comment: I edited your problem statement, to make it consistent with the answers.  Can you verify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More simply, just use $|s|\le\sqrt{s^2+t^2}$ and $|t|\le\sqrt{s^2+t^2}$, and you'll get
$$\left|\frac{3s^2t+s^2t^2}{\sqrt{s^2+t^2}}\right|\le 3(s^2+t^2) + (s^2+t^2)^{3/2},$$
and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

for your second Limit we have by $AM-GM$: $$\sqrt{s^2+t^2}\geq 2^{1/2}|st|^{1/2}$$
thus
$$\frac{|st|}{\sqrt7s^2+t^2}\le \frac{|st|}{2^{1/2}|st|^{1/2}}=\frac{1}{2^{1/2}}|st|^{1/2}$$ and this tends to Zero if $s,t$ tends to zero